# Magento checkout form element email.html page edit problem

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to customize email.html file but my changes not reflect why?... only changes reflect on .phtml but not html pages

Answer (score 0):

**run below CMD**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf generated/*
```

I hope it help..!!!